# jQuery .after with effect

Tags: jquery

i would like to ask, if is it possible to use .after function in correlation with some effect like fadeIn or so.

The whole flow should work like this:

1. get some AJAX content depend on user action (.click or so)
2. render response html right after current element

I already try to mix .get, .after, .show or .fadeIn methods, but without success.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @show some code what you tried

Comment: Do you have any code? You need to have an element to append after to. I'm not sure how you are trying to do it though. Are you doing $(element).after(data) in the success method of ajax or what?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy

```
jQuery.ajax({
url:"//Your URL//"
success: function(response){
jQuery(".defineYOURSELECTOR").after(jQuery(response).fadeIn());
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can simply do that in the callback:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'Some\Url',
   data: { prop: 'someData' },
   success: function(response)
   {
        var element = $('<div/>');
        element.html(response);
        element.hide();

        $('#someElement').after(element);
        element.fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Get the data. Setup the UI, insert that hidden, and then call FadeIn on that item.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native way to do this, but how about this...

```
var target = $('#someEl'); // existing element
$.get('example.php', function(response) {
    var newEl = $(response);
    newEl.hide().insertAfter(target).slideDown('slow');
});
```

This uses the following jQuery functions:

- [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get)
- [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)
- [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter)
- [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown)

Basically, the idea is to construct the element before you insert it into the document (using the [jQuery constructor `$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)), then insert it, then show it.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you guys. lonesomeday solution work lika a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$('<div></div>').hide().html(ajaxResult).insertAfter(target).fadeIn();
```

`ajaxResult` is the HTML that came back from the server, `target` is your "current" element (after which the new one will be inserted).